# Multiple language support not working using sharedpreference in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, multilingual

I'm trying to implement **multiple language support** in my applicaiton.

My app contains two activities namely **MainActivity.class** and **NextActivity.class**.

When the user selects any language option from the **MainActivity.class**, i will save the selected language in `sharedpreference` and get the `sharedpreference` language in next page to change the language type. But unable to change the language type.

Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue? Thanks for your precious time!..

**strings.xml (values-fr)**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">myAPP</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello">Bonjour !..</string>
</resources>
```

**strings.xml (values-hi)**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">myAPP</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello">नमस्ते !..</string>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CheckBox chk_english, chk_french, chk_hindi;
Button btn_next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chk_french = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_french);
    chk_hindi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_hindi);
    btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    chk_french.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if (compoundButton.isChecked()) {
                chk_hindi.setChecked(false);
            }

            saveLanguage("fr");

        }
    });


    chk_hindi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if (compoundButton.isChecked()) {
                chk_french.setChecked(false);
            }
            saveLanguage("hi");
        }
    });


    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        }
    });


}


public void saveLanguage(String type) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_LANGUAGE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("myLanguage", type);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();

}}
```

**NextActivity.java**

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next_layout);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    loadLanguage();

}

public void loadLanguage() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_LANGUAGE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myLang = prefs.getString("myLanguage", "");

    if (myLang.equals("fr")) {
        setLanguage("fr");
    } else if (myLang.equals("hi")) {
        setLanguage("hi");
    } else if (myLang.equals("en")) {
        setLanguage("en");
    }

}

void setLanguage(String lang) {

    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.next_layout);

}}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout            
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="test.org.myapp.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp">



    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_french"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="French"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_hindi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hindi"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**next_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="test.org.myapp.NextActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put this log after sharedpreferences object creation Log.e("LanguageType", prefs.getString("myLanguage", "")); and check what your are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check Are you getting the sharedprefrence value by putting log, if yes then change your code to my below code.

```
Log.e("LanguageType", prefs.getString("myLanguage", ""));
```

Change your code to my below code,Sure it will work for you

```
public void loadLanguage() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_LANGUAGE", MODE_PRIVATE);
  //  String myLang = prefs.getString("myLanguage", "");

    if (prefs.getString("myLanguage", "").equals("fr")) {
        setLanguage("fr");
    } else if (prefs.getString("myLanguage", "").equals("hi")) {
        setLanguage("hi");
    } else if (prefs.getString("myLanguage", "").equals("en")) {
        setLanguage("en");
    }

}
```